# How can I import a very large csv into dynamodb?

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

So I have very large csv file in my s3 database (2 mil+  lines) and I want to import it to dynamodb.

What I tried:

1. Lambda
   I manage to get the lambda function to work, but only around 120k lines were imported to ddb after my function being timed out.
2. Pipeline
   When using pipeline it got stuck on "waiting for runner" followed by it stopping completely

Comment: I am not sure that AWS have a service for this outside of restoring tables that were backed up using AWS backup. Have you tried just running your lambda code on your local machine? As far as I know dynamodb is always available over the plain internet?

Comment: Why do you want to import the CSV into DynamoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a serverless approach to process the large `.csv` in small chunks with 2 Lambdas and a SQS Queue:

1. Using a one-off Reader Lambda, extract the primary key information for all records using [S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/selecting-content-from-objects.html) SQL to `SELECT s.primary_key FROM S3Object s`, querying the `.csv` in place.  See the [SelectObjectContent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_SelectObjectContent.html) API for details.
2. The Reader Lambda puts the primary keys into a SQS queue.  Add a Dead Letter Queue to capture errors.
3. Add the queue as a Writer Lambda's event source.  Enable batching. Limit concurrency if desired.
4. Parallel Writer Lambda invocations fetch records for its batch of primary keys from the `.csv` using S3 Select: `SELECT * WHERE s.primary_key IN ('id1', 'id2', 'id3') FROM S3Object s`
5. The Writer Lambda writes its batch of records to the DynamoDB table.

Comment: Thank you for your  response! My csv file does not have any unique identifiers for each row. First column is a country name and the others are just numbers. There are multiple rows with the same country

Comment: @Alec DynamoDB items must have a unique [Primary Key](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/primary-key-dynamodb-table/).  So for your migration to work, there must be some combination of columns in each `.csv` row that makes each row unique.  The S3 Select statements should query for those fields.